# How can i block a specific input from ps4 controller in a specific application?

Tags: windows, ps4

I don’t know if this can be coded or not, but I want to block the arrow keys from my controller in a specific application so that the application doesn’t receive the arrow key inputs.

Can anyone tell me if this can be done on Windows and what i need to use or something?
Thanks

I can't find any way to write it in code.